# How can I remove the 'RedirectedHwndHost' create by AirspaceDecorator

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a WPF camera Label with a WinForms element in it.

After creating (and destroying) several labels, There are many RedirectedHwndHost elements in the Visual Tree, and a black rectangle appears at the screen.

Is there any way to remove the `RedirectedHwndHosts`?

This is my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.CameraLabel">
    <Grid>
        <interop:AirspaceDecorator x:Name="airSpace" AirspaceMode="Redirect" IsInputRedirectionEnabled="True" IsOutputRedirectionEnabled="True">
            <WindowsFormsHost Name="pictureHost" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <forms:PictureBox x:Name="PicBox" Dock="Fill"></forms:PictureBox>
            </WindowsFormsHost>
        </interop:AirspaceDecorator>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The `RedirectedHwndHost` elements in the Visual Tree:

[image]

The black rectangle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

```
IList<RedirectedHwndHost> list = new List<RedirectedHwndHost>();
       
    foreach (RightPanel rp in this.windowPop.Children)
    {

        AirspaceDecorator hwndClipper = rp.AirspaceDecoratorToContain;
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(hwndClipper);
        if (count > 0)
        {
            RedirectedHwndHost hwndSourceHost = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(hwndClipper, 0) as RedirectedHwndHost;
            if (hwndSourceHost != null)
            {
                list.Add(hwndSourceHost);
                   
            }
        }

    }
    this.windowPop.Children.Clear();

    for (int i = 0;  i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i].Dispose();
    }
```

Clear the children first and dispose of the `RedirectedHwndHost` second – because some errors happened when I change the order.